# Converting from Kubuntu to Ubuntu in old install: Fixing the desktop

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, gnome-panel, migration

I've been using Kubuntu since 9.04 but I've decided to switch to Ubuntu (read: GNOME) now. I've installed `ubuntu-desktop` a while ago, I think the system was in 9.10 then. I'm now at 10.10, all via upgrades (never a reinstall).

Presumably because of this, I'm missing a few things in my GNOME when compared to a clean install of Ubuntu 10.10:

- Notifications (msn contact online, battery low, etc.) look out of style. They look like text clouds instead of shiny Ambiance boxes. This is how they look:

[image: Ugly Notification]

- I'm missing my name and shutdown options in the top right of the panel

How can I restore these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the session applet is installed,it may be a matter of simply right clicking the panel and choosing add to panel.
The Applet  you need for your name is "indicate applet session"

Comment: And somehow the notifications were fixed automatically after a reboot

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install `notify-osd` (To fix the notifications) and `indicator-applet` and  `indicator-applet-session` to fix your second problem.

Comment: According to the software center, I already have them

Answer (score 0):

Such settings are (most likely) controlled by config files in your home folder.  `.config/` has many, and there are many application-specific folders as well.  Finding which of these match up with the specific issues you having can be done with google's help.

Once you know what the application is, and where the offending settings are, remove the application, remove the settings file/folder (**after backing up**), and reinstall the application.